# Try, catch breaking Jenkins pipeline parseScript

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I tried to implement an automatic cleanup of a failed Jenkins pipeline, so that docker-compose will delete the Docker containers.

Unfortunately this creates an error in the run. What have I done wrong?

```
stage('Verification') {
  steps {
    try {
      sh '''
      docker-compose exec -T cli drush status
      docker-compose exec -T cli curl http://nginx:8080 -v
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "OK!"
      else
        echo "FAIL"
        /bin/false
      fi
      docker-compose down
      '''
    }
    catch (e) {
      sh 'docker-compose down'
      throw e
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 37: Expected a step @ line 37, column 9.
           try {
           ^

1 error

  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
  at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `try-catch` inside `script` step.

```
script {
  try {
  }
  catch(e) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`post` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) to tear down your docker-compose installation at the end of your job

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
              sh '''
                docker-compose exec -T cli drush status
                docker-compose exec -T cli curl http://nginx:8080 -v
              '''
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            sh 'docker-compose down'
        }
    }
}
```